# puppet mechanism to prevent overwrite of unmanaged file

Tags: ruby, puppet

I a writing a small module to manage commit hooks for several repositories.
However, some repositories already have a post-commit hook in place.
I would like a mechanism that would allow me to:

- Create a file if none present
- Manage a file, only if the file contains the string 'Managed by Puppet'

Is there such a mechanism?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you'd create resource definitions( `file` using templates for content) for both cases so that Puppet becomes the source of record. Strongly recommend this.

That being said if you want to use conditionals to only manage some of the content of some of the files, you can still use `file` resources with no `content` option to insure all the files exist and then use `exec` with either `onlyif` or `unless` options to manage the cases where you want to replace any content. See [exec options](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec). Again though, this would be somewhat of an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I will try and convince the teams in question for their post-commit files to move under puppet control.